# Codename One - How to close all Tabs (via code)

Tags: codenameone

I have `Tabs` component in my form. Tabs are used for navigation.
There are situations, where I need to close all tabs and open new one at index 0. To close all tabs I use this method:

```
void close(int from) {
    int to = tabs.getTabCount() - 1;
    for (int i = to; i >= from; i--) {
        tabs.removeTabAt(i);
    }
    if (from > 0)
        tabs.setSelectedIndex(from - 1);
}

void closeAll() {
    close(0);
}
```

This works, but not always. Sometimes I recieve two exceptions:

```
[EDT] 0:0:8,436 - Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - Index: 1, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.getComponentAt(Container.java:1551)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1520)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1509)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1522)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1509)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1406)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1333)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1307)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1250)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1535)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1482)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.paintDirty(CodenameOneImplementation.java:588)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.paintDirty(JavaSEPort.java:1279)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1077)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:999)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.getComponentAt(Container.java:1551)
    at com.codename1.ui.Tabs$1.actionPerformed(Tabs.java:573)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:45)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1154)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1098)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.flushEdt(Display.java:886)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.showModal(Form.java:1762)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showModal(Dialog.java:1085)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:553)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPackedImpl(Dialog.java:1389)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPacked(Dialog.java:1297)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showImpl(Dialog.java:1041)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1019)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:975)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:764)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:717)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:682)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:623)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:778)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1012)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

So what is **the right way to close all tabs**?

**ADDED**

Exceptions are thrown only if `closeAll()` is invoked from sheduled `Runnable`. I use `Runnable` to close tabs after tabs slide end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this works sometimes I would suggest checking where the remove all comes from and wrapping that with a `callSerially()`. There are two potential failures:

- EDT violation
- Event queue still has tasks to perform that rely on the tabs being there

Both issues will be resolved with a `callSerially`.